# IE 11 : How Can we Detect Browser Version IE 11 Using Java?

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11

All of you know I.E 11 was Released.!! Before that to detect the Browser Version in Java, Using

"`getHttpServletRequest().getHeader("User-Agent")`".

It gives the the Browser name and Version. But After Introducing I.E 11 User Agent MSIE was removed..

So that how can we get the version for I.E in JAVA.

If any help it would help me a lot...

Thank You...

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: He is asking how to get the version, not why it errors out...WHY DOWNVOTES?

Comment: @ Itay Moav -Malimovka , You are right . thanks for your support.. I'm asking How to Get the I E Version 11. I dont why Down Votes. Ok. anyone Please give me the Solution. i think i'm too late. because since IE 11 released almost 4 months back !

Comment: 2 possibilities - either IE isnt sending out a user-agent (VERY unlikely), of you have a bug in your code somewhere. posting the code would help.

Comment: @radai, Ok, IE doesn't Support "MSIE" after I.E 11. Here is My Code To Detect the Version,                                                      String browser[] = null;
String information=(String)browserMessage.getHttpServletRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");
String browserObj = com.browser.util.Util.getBrowserInfo(information);
BigDecimal browserversion = new BigDecimal("0");
browser = browserObj.split("-");

 if(browser[0].equals("MSIE")) {
 }

Answer (score 2):

```
getHttpServletRequest().getHeader("User-Agent")
```

This should not throw nullpointerexception. Instead it should give the text

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

for IE 11 in standards mode, and

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)
```

in compability view. You can match those if you want to. However, as mentioned in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx), user agent sniffing is not recommended.

Comment: In My application we using I.E Emulate Funcationality so that it is not possible.. we ge I.E 7 always.... any suggestion /?

Comment: @Ilayaraja I don't understand, why wouldn't it be possible?